# Proving a set $(X, \le)$ is well ordered.

Tags: well-orders

Give an example of a well ordered set $(X,\le)$ in which there exists an element $x_0$ such that there are infinitely many elements $x\in X$ such that $x\lt x_0$.

Let $X=${$A_i | i \in \mathbb N$}$\cup \mathbb N$ where $A_i=${$1,2,...,i$}. Let the relation be inclusion of sets. Here, $x_0=\mathbb N$ obviously.  I feel intuitively that my $X$ is well ordered but I'm unsure how to prove it.

Comment: To give an example of $(X,\le)$ you have to specify both $X$ and $\le.$ What is your order relation? We have to know what that is, before we can start to prove that it's a well-ordering.

Comment: @bof sorry! edited!

Comment: Once you have specified your order relation, think about the definition of a well-ordered set.  Show that your set and relation meet that definition.

Comment: Can you prove that $(X,\subseteq)$ is *linearly* ordered? Can you prove that $(\{A_i|i\in\mathbb N\},\subseteq)$ is well-ordered? Can you prove that a linearly ordered set, which is the union of two well-ordered subsets, is well-ordered?

Comment: $X=\{A_i | i \in \mathbb N\}\cup\{\mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $S\subseteq X$ be non-empty.

If $\mathbb{N}\notin S$, then
$$
S=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{A_i\}
$$
for a non-empty subset $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, it follows that there is a minimum element $i_o\in I$. Clearly, $A_{i_0}$ is the minimum of $S$.

The same applies if
$$
S=\{\mathbb{N}\}\cup\bigcup_{i\in I}\{A_i\}
$$
for a non-empty subset $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$.

If $S=\{\mathbb{N}\}$ then clearly $\mathbb{N}$ is the minimum of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use cardinality for the ordering relationship.  That is, $x_i \le x_j$ in your ordering when $|x_i| \le |x_j|$ using the common meaning for less-than or equal.

Effectively, your set is the natural numbers plus $\aleph_0$.  The well-ordering follows directly from that.